# What does `mv path` under windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, terminal, visual-studio-code

Accidentally, I typed

```
mv C:\User\username\Download
```

in the visual studio code console. To my surprise the folder completely disappeared. That's quite a thing! Under Linux nothing would happen. Where did the folder go? Is it completely deleted from the filesystem? Is there a way to prevent this weird behavior?

Comment: It probably moved the `Download` folder to whatever location you were currently working in.

Comment: Just found that ;-)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how did you *accidentally* enter a command that moved your entire `Download` folder?  What were you trying to do?

Comment: I wanted to move a file from inside the folder. I am not used to the terminal under W10 it does weird things... Funny thing, I can delete this folder under C:\User\username\ and create it at a different place, but I cannot delete the copy that I created using the terminal, due to permissions. That is so weird.

Answer (score 5):

`mv C:\Your\Path\Here` without a destination directory will move the directory in question into the current working directory.